# Simple Lagrangian with free bound and constraint

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics

Let $\alpha,\beta$ non-zero real numbers, $f$ a function of time. I define $L_1=\alpha f + \beta$ and $L_2=p(t) L_1$.

I want to minimize $\int_0^T L_2$ under the constraint $\int_0^T L_1=v$, with $T$ being a free boundary.

By setting $T=T_0 + \epsilon \tau $ ; $f=f_0 + \epsilon \phi $ ; $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \epsilon \mu $ ; and varying on $\epsilon$, I end up with 3 equations:

- $\partial_f L_2 + \lambda_0 \partial_f L_1 =0$
- $L_2(f(T)) + \lambda_0 L_1(f(T)) =0$
- $\int_0^T L_1=v$

Which can be simplified into:

- $(p(t)+\lambda_0)\alpha =0$ (1)
- $(p(T)+\lambda_0)\alpha f_0(T) =0$ (2)
- $\int_0^{T_0} (\alpha f_0 + \beta)=v$ (3)

I am confused from there:

- Does (3) implies that I can take any $\{f_0; T_0\}$ as long as $\int_0^{T_0} f_0 = (v-\beta T_0)/\alpha$ ?
- Condition to which  we must add $f_0(T_0)=0$ from (2)?
- (1) is the most surprising to me as I thought the $\lambda$ Lagrange multiplier should be a fixed real?
- I'm also surprised that there is no dependence in $p(t)$...

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Note that I will eventually want to impose $f \in [0;1]$, but I'm not sure how to do that formally.